# What archive type are ubuntu click packages?

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-touch, application-development

Deb files and RPMS are at the end of the day zip files with files inside of them in a particular place. I was debugging one of my applications and wanted to look inside of the click package but it doesn't appear to be a zip. Is it another type of archive type which I can look at or something completely different e.g. a binary format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither deb or rpm packages are zip files. Instead deb packages are [ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29) archives and rpm packages are compressed [cpio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) archives.

Click packages are deb packages with some additional content. You can read the official specification [here](https://click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thanks I had assumed they were zip because the gnome archive manager opened them. Used ar back when I worked with C so should be able to extract the stuff on the command line. I wonder why gnome archive manager doesn't open click packages like it does deb/rpms ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the content of a click file, rename it as .tar.gz and with Nautilus in your PC you'll can see it. Finally remove the .tar.gz extension.